# Clean up my gnupg keyring?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnupg

My gnupg keyring contains hundreds of unnecessary entries. How would I remove the expired, revoked and unsigned keys from it?

I would like to keep the keys that have signed my key, and import new keys only as required. I'd previously imported the entire web of trust for my key's signatories. It would seem that one of my key signers has picked up a very large number of signatures in his travels, and these are now clogging up my keyring.

Comment: I would use https://gpgtools.org/. It does not help to remove expired, though, but definitely eases management of gpg keys

Comment: The title does not match with what you want. You said "clean up my gnupg keyring", that means delete all keyring and the content said you only want to removed expired, revoked and unsinged keys.

Comment: @MaXi32 - that's not what "clean up" means at all.

Comment: I mean the title should say "How to remove expired, revoked and unsigned keys". I keep getting into your post from Google when I search "How to remove all gpg keys".

Comment: It's been up for 8 years with no complaints until today. “How to remove *all* gpg keys” is `rm -r ~/.gnupg`. This will remove your private keys too, but you did say *all* …

Answer (score 80):

From Charles Lockhart’s [GPG Cheat Sheet](http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~lockhart/gpg/):

> I've used `User Name` as being the name associated with the key. 
>   Sorry that isn't very imaginative. 
>   I *think* gpg is pretty wide in its user assignments,
>   e.g., the name for my private key is “Charles Lockhart”,
>   but I can reference that by just putting in “Lockhart”. 
>   That doesn't make any sense, sorry.
>
> ︙
>
> **to delete a public key (from your public key ring):**
>
> ```
> $ gpg --delete-key "User Name"
> ```
>
> This removes the public key from your public key ring.
>   NOTE: If there is a private key on your private key ring associated with this public key, you will get an error! You must delete your private key for this key pair from your private key ring first.
>
> **to delete a private key (a key on your private key ring):**
>
> ```
> $ gpg --delete-secret-key "User Name"
> ```
>
> This deletes the secret key from your secret key ring.

Comment: Thanks; that's a start, at least. I can use it to find and list the expired keys:
`gpg --list-keys | awk '/^pub.* \[expired\: / {id=$2; sub(/^.*\//, "", id); print id}' | fmt -w 999 | sed 's/^/gpg --delete-keys /;'`

Comment: `"User Name"` can also be the short public key

Comment: On gpg 2.2.20, the `--delete-key` and `--delete-secret-key` commands don't exist anymore.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg - I'm on 2.2.21 and `--delete-secret-key` just worked fine for me

Answer (score 19):

The man page of gpg advises against parsing the normal output of `--list-keys` but it offers parseable output with [`--with-colons`](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Input-and-Output.html#GPG-Input-and-Output).

This removes all public keys that are expired or revoked:

```
gpg --list-keys --with-colons \
  | awk -F: '$1 == "pub" && ($2 == "e" || $2 == "r") { print $5 }' \
  | xargs gpg --batch --yes --delete-keys
```

#### How does it work?

1. tell gpg to output keys in a parsable format (the docs for this format are a little hidden: the man page says they are in [`doc/DETAILS`](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/DETAILS;hb=refs/heads/master) in the source, my distro installed them in `/usr/share/doc/gunpg/DETAILS`)
2. tell awk to use colon as field delimiter: `-F:`
3. only select lines where the first field is "pub", these are public keys
4. only select lines where the second field is either "e" or "r", these are revoced or expired keys
5. print only field five of the selected lines, that is the key id
6. use xargs to hand the lines to gpg and delete them

Comment: Perhaps replace `--delete-keys` with `--delete-secret-and-public-key` to get everything.

Comment: @MaXi32, I just looked at my local man page and it does list that option.

Comment: Best answer and `--delete-secret-and-public-key` is the way to go. With that said, it's not a bad idea to keep expired keys in case you need to verify something old. I don't use gpg like that though.

Comment: This would make a nice script to run as an annual cron job

Answer (score 9):

I have a bash script scheduled to run weekly from cron to handle this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Clean up the GPG Keyring.  Keep it tidy.
# blog.lavall.ee
 
echo -n "Expired Keys: "
for expiredKey in $(gpg2 --list-keys | awk '/^pub.* \[expired\: / {id=$2; sub(/^.*\//, "", id); print id}' | fmt -w 999 ); do
    echo -n "$expiredKey"
    gpg2 --batch --quiet --delete-keys $expiredKey >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -n "(OK), "
    else
        echo -n "(FAIL), "
    fi
done
echo done.

echo -n "Update Keys: "
for keyid in $(gpg -k | grep ^pub | grep -v expired: | grep -v revoked: | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1); do
    echo -n "$keyid"
    gpg2 --batch --quiet --edit-key "$keyid" check clean cross-certify save quit > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -n "(OK), "
    else
        echo -n "(FAIL), "
    fi
done
echo done.

gpg2 --batch --quiet --refresh-keys > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Refresh OK"
else
     echo "Refresh FAIL."
fi
```

Comment: What is `$2` in the `awk` section of your script ? And while at it, what is `$1` ? Cheers.

Comment: Normal awk syntax for second and first (space-separated) field in the current line of input.

Comment: I don't understand why doing local cleanup of keys and then… downloading all the stuff you just deleted from keyserver again with `--refresh-keys`. I'd put the refresh in the middle of the script, not the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
% gpg --edit-key KEYID
gpg> clean
User ID [...]: 139 signatures removed
gpg> save
% gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.18
[...]
```

Comment: When I follow those steps and then check with ` gpg --list-keys` I keep seing the same old expired keys...

Comment: `gpg clean` doesn't remove expired keys, only expired signatures

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Expired Keys: "
list_expired_keys="$(gpg2 --list-keys | grep -1 pub | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | awk '/^pub.* \[expired\: / {id=$7; sub(/^.*\//, "", id); print id}' | fmt -w 999)";
list_revoked_keys="$(gpg2 --list-keys | grep -1 pub | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | awk '/^pub.* \[revoked\: / {id=$7; sub(/^.*\//, "", id); print id}' | fmt -w 999)";
for key in $list_expired_keys $list_revoked_keys; do
    echo -n "$key"
    gpg2 --batch --quiet --delete-keys $key >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -n "(OK), "
    else
        echo -n "(FAIL), "
    fi
done
echo done.
```

here is a bash-script doing the job. It is an adaption of https://superuser.com/a/859739 for gpg2 where the key id is in the second line.

Comment: pipein to `fmt -w 999` is not needed.